# GDB convenience variable doesn't expand in .gdbinit

Tags: debugging, gdb, arm-none-eabi-gcc

I run `gdb` with a `.gdbinit` file, which has some convenience variables that just won't expand.

### 1. My setup

I wrote the following `.gdbinit` file to flash an executable to a microcontroller through a blackmagic probe (see https://github.com/blacksphere/blackmagic/wiki):

```
# .gdbinit file:
# ------------------------------------------- #
#              GDB commands                   #
#              FOR STM32F767ZI                #
# ------------------------------------------- #
target extended-remote $com
monitor version
monitor swdp_scan
attach 1
file mcu_application.elf
load
start
detach
quit
```

The blackmagic probe attaches itself to a COM-port, which can be different on one computer vs another. Therefore, I don't want to hardcode that in the `.gdbinit` file. A GDB convenience variable looked like the most elegant solution:

https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_59.html

So I use the convenience variable `$com` in the `.gdbinit` file and I define it on the commandline when I invoke GDB:

```sh
arm-none-eabi-gdb -x .gdbinit -ex "set $com = \"COM9\""
```

### 2. The error

GDB starts but throws an error message:

```sh
.gdbinit:6: Error in sourced command file:
$com: No such file or directory.
```

It looks like GDB doesn't recognize the `$com` convenience variable. So I check if GDB actually stored the variable:

```sh
(gdb) show convenience
$com = "COM9"
$trace_file = void
$trace_func = void
$trace_line = -1
$tracepoint = -1
$trace_frame = -1
$_inferior = 1
...
```

This proves that GDB correctly stored it as `"COM9"`. The problem is therefore a failure to expand it.

### 3. Some more trials

As I observed the failure to expand `$com` while executing `.gdbinit`, I thought it might work to issue the commands directly in GDB:

```sh
(gdb) set $com = "COM9"

(gdb) show convenience
$com = "COM9"
$trace_file = void
$trace_func = void
...

(gdb) target extended-remote $com
$com: No such file or directory.
```

But the error persists.

### 4. Questions

Do you know a way to make the convenience variables in GDB work? Or do you know of another mechanism to reach the same goal?

---

### 5. The solution

Thank you @Mark Plotnick for your answer! As you suggested, I gave my `.gdbinit` file the following content:

```
define flash-remote
  target extended-remote $arg0
  monitor version
  monitor swdp_scan
  attach 1
  file mcu_application.elf
  load
  start
  detach
  quit
end
```

However, I had to remove the quotes around the argument `COM9` when invoking GDB. So instead of:

```sh
arm-none-eabi-gdb -x .gdbinit -ex "flash-remote \"COM9\""
```

I invoke GDB this way:

```sh
arm-none-eabi-gdb -x .gdbinit -ex "flash-remote COM9"
```

Now it works! You saved my day!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convenience variables are only expanded in certain contexts - mostly expressions - such as the arguments to `print`, `x`, `eval`, `set`, and `if`.

You could use `eval` to do what you want:

```
eval "target extended-remote %s", $com
```

But - and this is a big but - until recently, when evaluating expressions, gdb would store string values in the address space of the target, which requires a running process. So on older gdbs, you may get the error message **evaluation of this expression requires the target program to be active**.

Gdb does have a more general macro facility: [user-defined commands](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Define.html#Define).

One possibility is to put this in .gdbinit:

```
define flash-remote
  target extended-remote $arg0
  monitor version
  monitor swdp_scan
  attach 1
  file mcu_application.elf
  load
  start
  detach
  quit
end
```

And invoke gdb like this:

```
arm-none-eabi-gdb -ex "flash-remote \"COM9\""
```

Comment: Thank you @Mark Plotnick. It works beautifully! I'll put a bounty on this question and award it to you to express my gratitude for your help. You saved my day (and actually my whole week).

Comment: Hi @Mark Plotnick. I just awarded the bounty +100 to you to show my appreciation :-)

Comment: @K.Mulier Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

GDB [manual](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Startup.html#Startup) clearly documents that `.gdbinit` is evaluated before any `-ex` commands.

You could write a trivial shell wrapper that creates a temporary `/tmp/.gdbinit.$unique_suffix` with appropriate substitutions, invokes `gdb -x /tmp/.gdbinit....`, and removes the temporary file once GDB exits.

Comment: Hi @EmployedRussian, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately that doesn't work. Even if I don't use a `.gdbinit` file at all, and just type the commands manually in gdb, the `$com` variable doesn't expand (see paragraph 3 in my question).

Comment: Hi @EmployedRussian, thanks for your help. Your suggestion would certainly work.
However, the solution I'm looking for should fit elegantly in our new IDE for microcontrollers (I'm in the startup "Embeetle", building a new IDE for microcontrollers). The solution must therefore be immediately obvious to users who want to edit the `.gdbinit` file themselves (we strive for an IDE that doesn't hide anything behind the scenes, but uses only industry-standard config files, see https://embeetle.com/#comics/cfg_as_code).

Answer (score 1):

The format for selecting a COM port on Windows is "//./COM9", so your test in GDB should have used:

```
$com = COM9
target extended-remote //.$com
```

I have not tested this, however I would expect it to work.